# How can I add a package collection to my Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, package

In Xcode 12.5 with iOS deployment target 14.5 I want to import the `swift-collections` library to use module `OrderedDictionary`.

When I add the following URL `https://developer.apple.com/swift/packages/collections/apple.json` as a package repository I get the following error:

[image]

I assume this is an authorisation issue. Where should I enter my credentials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Swift 5.5 and Xcode 13+

**Package Collections** is introduce in Swift 5.5 with Xcode 13.

From [Swift.org](https://swift.org/blog/package-collections/)

> You can add it using the new package-collection add option from the SwiftPM command line

```
$ swift package-collection add https://developer.apple.com/swift/packages/collections/apple.json
```

After firing the above command, select your project in the Xcode project navigator, select it again in the projects and targets list, and switch to the Swift Packages tab and click the + button below the Packages list, and you'll see a collections list. And add swift-collections package from the list.

[image]

Note: Ensure you have at least Swift 5.5 installed. You can check which version of Swift you're running with `swift --version`.

### Below Xcode 13

Valid URL is: `https://github.com/apple/swift-collections`

You have to add swift collections package instead of json.

Check `Using Swift Collections in your project` section from [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections#using-swift-collections-in-your-project)

After installing you will get the following tab for selection target. And select OrderedCollections target.

Documentation :
https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md

[image]

Comment: This works! I was trying the json because I was following the instructions on https://swift.org/blog/package-collections/ but I've just realised that's for Xcode 13.